# Java - Importar System.out

Tags: java

Por que esto no funciona?

```
import java.lang.System;
out.println("Hola mundo");
```

Perdón que no pueda poner el código completo, pero estoy desde el celular.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Básicamente tienes que hacer referencia a qué clase pertenece la propiedad `out`. Por mucho que lo importes, Java no reconoce `out`, por lo tanto tendrás que hacer `System.out.println("Hola mundo");`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Y no es posible crear una variable al estilo de lo que se hace con Scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que hacer referencia a qué clase pertenece la propiedad `out`. Por mucho que lo importes, Java no reconoce `out`, por lo tanto tendrás que hacer:

```
System.out.println("Hola mundo");
```

Si quieres simplificarlo podrías hacer algo así:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class HelloWorld
{
  static PrintStream imprimir = System.out;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    imprimir.print("HOLA");
    imprimir.print(" MUNDO");
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Mi duda más que nada, ahora que me das ese ejemplo, es porque tampoco funciona System salida = System.out.

Comment: @FermatsTheorem `System.out` no devuelve un objeto `System` sino un objeto de la clase `PrintStream`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar algo prácticamente igual a lo que pretendes usando **imports estáticos**.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    out.println("Hola mundo");
  }
}
```

Con el import estático básicamente lo que haces es definir una variable o método de otra clase para que se llame con sintaxis como si estuviera definido en la clase actual.
En este caso `out` es un objeto de tipo `PrintStream` y lo usamos como si fuera una variable declarada a nivel de clase.

Adicionalmente te dejo [una liga](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-static-import/) con más información.